# Linked list - Inserting in middle, linking new node

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

**Look at the last function i_at() at bottom.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define nl printf("\n")
#define pf printf
#define si(a) scanf("%d",&a)
#define sc(a) scanf("%c",&a);
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *first,*last,*damn,*temp,*prev,*newnode;
void i_beg();
void i_end();
void display();
void del();
void i_at();
struct node *create(int);
main()
{
    int val,i,j; char key;val=1;
    while(val<6 && val>0){
        pf("\n1.Start \t2.End \t3.Display\t4.Delete\t5.Insert\t6.Exit\n------------------------------------------------\n");
        si(val);
        if(val==6)exit(0);
        else{
            switch(val){
                case 1: i_beg(); break;
                case 2: i_end(); break;
                case 3: display();break;
                case 4: del(); break;
                case 5: i_at();break;
                case 6: exit(0);break;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct node * create(int val){
    newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof( struct node));
    if(newnode == NULL)
    {
        pf("Oops! You have gone out of memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode -> val = val;
        newnode -> next = NULL;
        return newnode;
    }

}
void i_beg(){
    int x;
    //if(first -> val == last -> val && first == NULL) pf("Only one node exists!!!\n ");
    pf("Enter a value to insert\t");
    si(x);  newnode = create(x);
    if(first == last && first == NULL)
    {
        first = last = newnode;
        first -> next = NULL;
        last -> next = NULL;
        pf("\n %d inserted at first\n",x);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = first;
        first = newnode;
        first -> next = temp;
        pf("\n %d inserted at first\n",x);
    }
}
void i_end(){
    int x;
    //if(first -> val == last -> val && first == NULL) pf("Only one node exists!!!\n ");
    pf("Enter a value to insert\t");
    si(x);  newnode = create(x);
    if(first == last && first == NULL)
    {
        first = last = newnode;
        first -> next = NULL;
        last -> next = NULL;
        pf("\n %d inserted at last\n",x);
    }
    else
    {
        last -> next = newnode;
        last = newnode;
        last -> next = NULL;
        pf("\n %d inserted at last\n",x);
    }
}
void display(){
    prev = first;
    while(prev != NULL)
    {
        pf("%d -> ",prev -> val);
        prev  = prev -> next;
    }pf(" NULL");
    nl;
}
void del(){
    pf("Enter the position to delete\t");
    int i,pos;si(pos);
    for(prev = first,i=1 ; i<pos-1 ; prev=prev->next,i++);// not i< pos but i<pos-1
    temp = prev -> next;
    prev -> next =  temp->next;
}
void i_at(){
    pf("Enter the position to add after this position\t");
    int i,pos;si(pos);
    for(prev = first,i=1 ; i<pos ; prev=prev->next,i++);
    pf("Enter a value to insert\t");
    si(i);  newnode = create(i);
    temp = prev;

    // order of these statements is important
    newnode -> next = temp -> next;
    prev -> next = newnode;
    pf("%d inserted after position %d\n",i,pos);
}
```

If i write the lines as

```
prev -> next = newnode;
newnode -> next = temp -> next;
```

then the display() function is going wrong. But if I reverse the order of these two lines as

```
newnode -> next = temp -> next;
prev -> next = newnode;
```

Then the code is working. It's just a matter of linking the new node to the linked list. Then,Why the code is wrong if I swap the order of that two lines as shown in the code?

Ex: *To connect b to a&c it doesn't matter if connect (b->c first, a->b second)OR(a->b first, b->c second.*
Where is  the mistake?

Comment: Because `temp` and `prev` both point to the same object.

Comment: I see you have tagged this as c++ rather than c.  +1 for picking just one, but if you are using c++, why are you using malloc and not new?

Comment: For linked lists it usually helps a lot to do all the operations on paper first, and then implement those operations in code.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I think he is using C as seen from the functions and headers he is using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do:

```
temp = prev;
```

you are not copying the struct, you are just aliasing the name `prev` with the name `temp`, since both are *pointers*.

So when you do:

```
prev -> next = newnode;
newnode -> next = temp -> next;
```

you are changing the value of the field `next` of both `prev` and `temp`, and the second statement is incorrect.

In the other case the order of updating is correct.

Comment: If it's possible to copy a struct, then, Will my code be correct in both ways?Is there any method to copy a struct object. _If temp is a copy of prev_

Comment: You *can* copy a struct in C, by simply assign it to another one, but note that both `temp` and `prev` are two *pointers* to a struct, not struct themselves.

Comment: Finally, note also that in this case the usual way of managing such insertion is like that in the second (correct) case, not to allocate a new structure and copy in it the old val and update the pointers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We can do a deep copy of a struct by assigning it to another one. Here, `temp = prev` does a shallow copy of the same reference.

Answer (score 3):

`temp` and `prev` have the same value, and point to the same object.  Therefore the lines could be written as either:

```
newnode -> next = prev -> next;
prev -> next = newnode;
```

or

```
prev -> next = newnode;
newnode -> next = prev -> next;
```

Clearly only one of these is going to work.

As an aside, you will find the code easier to read in the long run if you declare local variables in each function as you need them.  None of the variables in the function of interest needed to be global, and it makes it much harder to reason about large programs.